# Python multiprocessing to iterate over a list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using python 2.7.5 (can't upgrade at the moment ): )
This is my multiprocessing code, everything is in the same python script:

```
def get_data(self, data):
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    data_to_add = list()
    print("Gathering data")
    for machine in data:
        data_to_add.extend(pool.map(create_doc_struct, [machine]))
    pool.close()
    return data_to_add
```

This is the create_doc_struct function:

```
def create_doc_struct(_machine):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    export_json = my_class.get_collection(my_class.export_collection).find({})
for exported_data in export_json:
    if _machine["Hostname"] == exported_data["name"]:
        d = {
            "hostname": _machine["Hostname"],
            "server": exported_data["Server"]
        }
        return d
```

When I run the script, it looks like 8 threads are spawned but when I run with one thread or 8 threads, the script run time is the same.

I tried adding more vCPUs (currently 16) and RAM (64 GB) but it still takes the same time to complete the run.

To me it seems like the multiprocessing code is not working or only one thread is running this function.
Sometimes it also seems to be slowing down during the run.

Am I missing something in my code?
How can I solve this?

Comment: You only have one item in your iterable `[machine]`, so there will be only one task for one worker-process. Pass `data` directly as `iterable`-argument to `pool.map` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
I will try this tomorrow and see if that works :)

Comment: It worked for me, thanks @Darkonaut !